# Disable Google Play publish in Codemagic

Tags: android, codemagic

I have an app that I run through Codemagic to send to a group of early adopters. I want to only create the Android and iOS packages and have them email. I have done this before but now I see the publish to Google Play is enabled and the build fails.
[image]

You can see that the box to disable the process is disabled. When I click on the blue button nothing happens.

How do I disable Google Play publishing?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new project and was able to avoid this setting.